# C# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

Here is the code:

```
protected void addBtstu1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection stu = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DB; User Id=sa; password=123"))
        {
            stu.Open();

            using (var stucom = new SqlCommand("Insert into Student([student_registerno],student_name,student_hkid,student_parentname1,student_parent2,student_address,student_phone) value (@registerno,@name,@hkid,@parentname1,@parentname2,@address,@phone)"))
            {
                stucom.Connection = stu;
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerno", sturegisterno.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", stuname.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hkid", stuid.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentname1", stuparentname1.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentname2", stuparentname2.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", stuaddress.Text);
                stucom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", stuphoneno.Text);
                stucom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                stu.Close();
            }
}
```

When I try to execute, the error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on ExecuteNonQuery" appear.

I have read some of investigation here before but seem not to much useful.

Does any one can give some suggestion to solve it?

Comment: There is more information included with the exception that we will need to provide good help for this.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code on stucom.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'value'.

Comment: Always observe the stacktrace, as it is giving you plenty of information. Also, try debuging the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN your SQL, "value" should actually be "Values" (plural).

```
using (var stucom = new SqlCommand("Insert into Student([student_registerno],student_name,student_hkid,student_parentname1,student_parent2,student_address,student_phone) values (@registerno,@name,@hkid,@parentname1,@parentname2,@address,@phone)"))
```